# How can I use the images on Bing legally?

Tags: web, licensing

I would like to use the images that appear on [Bing's homepage](http://bing.com/), can I just use these or will I need to link to these, publish them with a photo credit, or have written permission?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can't just use them without permission.** See the ⓘ symbol in the lower right corner of the image on Bing, right next to the arrows for previous and next image? That shows you the copyright information for that particular image. You could follow that information and get a license — most of the images are from stock photo agencies and I doubt Bing has an exclusive right to them.

Note that clicking the ⓘ doesn't take you to a licensing page. It takes you to a web search for the title of the image, which tends to lead to all sorts of *different* places. You'll need to investigate each rights-holder a little more closely on your own.

Note 2: this is really off-topic for this site. I'm voting for it to be closed as off-topic even though I hope this answer helps you.

Comment: PS: to find images you _can_ use without additional license, see http://search.creativecommons.org/, and [this question](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6842/how-to-attribute-flickr-creative-commons-photos-online) for info on required attribution if you do find something you like.

Comment: I agree, I have edited to make it more about the licensing rather than stealing images.

Comment: Edited my answer to match your edit. But I'm afraid it's still off topic based on how we've generally defined the site in the past — licensing questions from the _photographer's_ side are okay, but questions about how to find images to buy or use from the consumer/web designer side belong elsewhere. (We can discuss this further on http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/ if you like.)

Comment: I think thats fine, I agree that its off topic, just thought i'd change it so it didn't reflect that the OP was trying to steal images. Thanks

Comment: Fair enough. :)