# How to attribute Wikimedia Photos?

Tags: legal, attribution

I am using three photos on my landing page which will be used for advertising on Google. On the top part of the page is a slideshow with three photos, and then on the remaining part of the page, three photos appear again on the left side of three paragraphs.

The Photos are:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:New_Long-Haul_Cabin_-_8967381715.jpg
  Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 2.0 Generic license
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:OpenSkies_Biz_Bed_cabin_(4).jpg
  Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported license
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:OpenSkies_Biz_Bed_cabin_(1).jpg
  Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported license

How do I attribute these photos and the slideshow?

Ideally I would like to have a link in the footer called credits, which launches a lightbox showing all attributions. Will that be enough and what exactly should I write?

Comment: Be a little cautious when using images from Wikimedia Commons that seem "commercial grade". I'm not saying that the user FlyOpenSkies isn't the legitimate rights holder for those images, but they did also upload [this one](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:OpenSkies_logo.jpg) which has a contradictory "all rights reserved" statement in the author field, which is a red flag that they may not quite "get" the Creative Commons idea... people *do* upload things there with completely invalid licenses sometimes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to attribute Flickr Creative Commons photos online?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6842/how-to-attribute-flickr-creative-commons-photos-online)

Comment: @junkyardsparkle Agreed entirely. There's absolutely no way that a logo with the British Airways wordmark in it would be released under a CC license.

Comment: Philip, junkyardsparkle, I don't know why you have that belief. The source appears to be https://www.flickr.com/people/austrianairlines/, which claims to be official, and the license there is absolutely CC-BY. And the claim to legitimacy is backed by a redirect from http://flickr.austrian.com/. It's all publicity shots, and I see no reason they _wouldn't_ have chosen a license which allows sharing.

Comment: The logomark file may be under CC-BY without comment on separate trademark rights. See https://wiki.creativecommons.org/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Can_I_place_a_trademark_on_a_work_and_offer_the_work_under_a_CC_license_without_also_licensing_or_otherwise_affecting_rights_in_the_trademark.3F_If_so.2C_how.3F for Creative Commons' FAQ on the issue.

Comment: @mattdm not that one, but the one linked by junkyardsparkle. The AA one I agree is definitely CC-BY.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that one is definitely suspicious. But it's also not one of the ones being asked about.

Comment: @mattdm True, but it would make me paranoid about using the other two "OpenSkies" images which are being asked about.

Comment: @mattdm -  Wasn't trying to instill paranoia, just a little due caution based on some things I've seen on Commons. It's a good idea to sniff test flickr sources when given, as you demonstrated; ["flickrwashing"](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Questionable_Flickr_images) is very much a thing.

Answer (score 3):

The photos are licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution / Share-Alike license (the first is [CC-BY-SA-2.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/); the others are [CC-BY-SA-3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). Basically, you need a credit line with the author and license. The first photo's Summary block has a source URL of Flickr, so it is reasonable to construe that that indicates a requirement to list the originating URL in the credit line.

According to the [Wikimedia Commons: Credit Line article](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Credit_line), your credit lines should be something along the lines of:

- © Austrian Airlines Group / http://www.flickr.com/photos/48248150@N04/8967381715/ / CC-BY-SA-2.0
- © Wikimedia Commons User:FlyOpenSkies / CC-BY-SA-3.0
- © Wikimedia Commons User:FlyOpenSkies / CC-BY-SA-3.0

Mote: the URL of the first photo doesn't need to be spelled out; it can be a clickable link with human-radable text, as in just: [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/48248150@N04/8967381715/).

Comment: Great. Thanks. Can I put a credit link at bottom of page which opens a light box and put line that the "page includes creative with following licenses" and include licenses below it? Also, will this also cover license for slideshow?

Comment: @Sal I'm not quite sure what you're asking (I don't know what you mean by "light box"), but: 1), I'm not a lawyer, so weigh my advice accordingly; and 2), typically you want to put the license on the same page where the photo is used. Having an action "separate" them (i.e., having the reader click on a link) may or not be in the spirit of the license.

Comment: Thanks for update. Lightbox is simply an overlay popup to show content. it's not a separate window or tab but shows over same page.